# Question on Properties of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Given $f : [0,1]$ →$ (0,1)$ is continuous function. If $F ⊆ [0,1]$ is closed set then $f(F)$ is closed set in $R$ ? If possible provide an example of such a  non constant function f.

I know that, if $I$ is closed and bounded interval and $f: I→ R$ is continuous function on $I$ then $f(I)$ is closed and bounded interval. 
But how can we apply above result to given question, because in given question codomain is $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can apply that result, as $A = f[[0,1]]$ will be a compact and connected subset of $(0,1)$, as these properties are preserved by continuous maps, so $A$ is also a compact and connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (as compact and connected are intrinsic properties, it doesn't matter in what larger space you consider them).

A connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is order-convex and thus an interval or segment, but if that connected set is compact as well, it should be closed and bounded too, which only leaves the option $f[[0,1]] = [a,b]$ for some $a \le b$ in $(0,1)$.

As an example of such a function, consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}x$, which has image $[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}] \subset (0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

The general proof is a classic, I'm pretty sure you'll be able to find it in your textbook.

As per the example, let $f(x) = 1/2, \forall x \in [0,1]$, then $f([0,1]) = \{1/2\}$ a closed and bounded set.

Edit: The example above is perfectly valid. I just wrote it before the OP added the restriction $f$ non constant.

Comment: Sorry I had edited the question. I need example of non constant function, if there is any? Further I need proof of above fact too.

Comment: Pick any line, $f(x) = 1/2 + x/4$

Comment: So what will be image of [0, 1] under f(x) = 1/2 + x/4 how it will be closed?

Comment: Let's see. A line is a monotonic function, in this case is increasing, and the values in the extremes of the interval are 1/2 and 3/4...

Comment: Thanks got the example. But i am unable to prove theorem and in fact unable to find it in any text.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Answer (score 0):

If f:[0,1] -> (0,1) is continuous and K closed subset [0,1],
then K is compact, hence f(K) is compact.  Thus f(K)
is closed for compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are
closed and any f in C([0,1], (0,1)) is an example.

As regard extending the codomain from (0,1) to R,
note that if f:X -> Y is continuous and Y subset Z,
then f:X -> Z is continuous, basically because the extension
to Z is adding no new points to f(X),the range of f.